# I want to know expressions for 4-currents for wave functions having spin 1 (rest mass =0 and rest mass not equal 0) and spin 2

Tags: quantum-mechanics

I know expressions for 4-currents of wave functions with spin equal to $0$ and $1/2$.
like $$\psi^*\partial^\mu\psi-\partial^\mu\psi^*\psi$$ for $s=0$ , or $$\bar\psi\gamma^\mu\psi$$ for $s=1/2$
What is it for $s=1$ and $s=2$ ?
Poynting vector for $s=1$ rest mass =0.
But for rest mass  not equal to 1? (Proca equation 4-current?)
For Gravitons s=2 , is there a 4-currrent of gravitons ?

Comment: Hello! It is preferable to use MathJax (LaTeX) to display formulas. You can find a tutorial at [MathJax basic tutorial and quick reference](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/). Please [edit] your question accordingly. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Conserved currents are associated to continuous symmetries of the model, that's what [Nöther's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noether%27s_theorem) is all about. The vector current for the free Dirac theory is associated to the $U(1)$ symmetry of the system. It's the same symmetry of the complex Klein-Gordon type field, which is where the first current comes from.

Conserved currents have nothing to do with the spin of the particle which the lagrangian describes, so asking the question whether such conserved currents exist for spin 1 or 2 field, is nonsense. Given a theory for a spin 1 or 2 field, one finds the symmetries of the system and only then can find the conserved currents.

Comment: I have a theory of  interspersing GR and QFT ideas and for that I need some quantum currents of various state functions psi. Each current expression varies according to spin of the particle.  I just need some ready-made known expressions for s=1 and s=2. Can one talk of a graviton current? Or Proca current or Poynting currrent (for photons)? Will the Proca equation current describe the W and Z boson currents? Graviton propagator is  given in the book by Peskin and Schroeder (page 126). How does one get an expression for a current from any propagator or lagrangean?